# How check if Vue is in development mode?

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

When I run my Vue app, the console shows:

```
You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

So now I want to check if Vue is in development from inside my templates by using:

```
console.log("mode is " + process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

But that only logs `undefined`
Is there a different way to find the NODE_ENV in Vue?

My webpack config has this part:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Perhaps relevant: I use typescript, so I included this type declaration:

```
declare var process: {
    env: {
        NODE_ENV: string
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, why would you want to view the environment from your Vue components? This is only relevant in Server Side Rendering approaches. Typically, running a Vue build will generate a dist folder with static files. Hence checking the environment on that is useless.

Comment: I reckon that `new webpack.DefinePlugin({ process: JSON.stringify(process) })` with `DefinePlugin` would do it.

Comment: @Imre_G I want to prefill form fields only when I am working in a dev environment. When the site is deployed, the form fields should not be prefilled.

Comment: How are you bundling your code in development and production mode?

Comment: @Kokodoko, I think that the overhead of creating that doesn't justify the cost of getting it working. My suggestion would be to prefill it and remove it before you run the build. Obviously, that is a possible point of failure, but my experience is that you will keep 1 or 2 of these in each project. Maybe someone else here has a better idea. I would be interested to learn.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn’t realise that ENV_MODE is not available in the browser. I guess I could just make a global `window.debug = true`. Would there be a way to include that line during the compile process?

Comment: You might find this link useful: https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/environment-variables/

Comment: @Kokodoko just realized a simple way that a friend of mine implemented. Just do `if (window.location.href === 'localhost')` or something like that. So easy that I didn't think of it then and I didn't think of it now again :)

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for why. The question is how. For me, my why is that I don't want to hook into console.error when developing (it throws off the lines where the error is reported if I do), but want it in production bc I can remotely get that info. This happens to be a PWA that also works offline.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `Vue 3` and `Vite` projects, use this from any `js` or `vue` file in your project:

```
console.log(import.meta.env.DEV)
console.log(import.meta.env.PROD)
```

returns `boolean value`, depending on your environment.

Answer (score 49):

If you started with vue-cli (default webpack) then this should work:

```
  connection: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? 'ws://localhost:5000'
    : 'wss://myawsomeproject.org'
```

Comment: yeah, but process.env.NODE_ENV is not defined... that was the problem.

Comment: I didn't start with vue-cli, but I got this working, thanks!

Comment: not work . window.process is undefined in chrome in production mode. (npm run build)

Answer (score 35):

Webpack is used for almost all of my Vue projects, so I check to see if `webpackHotUpdate` is present.

```
 if (webpackHotUpdate) {
      console.log('In Dev Mode');
 }
```

It's present in the `window` object if the webpack dev server is running.

Comment: maybe you should check whether webpackHotUpdate is not undefiend

Comment: Where do you do this? I'm getting `'webpackHotUpdate' is not defined`

Comment: @CpILL I haven't done it in a while, but it's in the `window` object. So try checking for `window.webpackHotUpdate`. I haven't worked with the latest Vuejs, so things may have also changed.

Comment: works.
`const isProd = (window.webpackHotUpdate===undefined);`

Answer (score 32):

I know this is an old question but it may be helpful to new VueJS users to know this solution that I found in the current version of Vue (3.11):

When running in dev mode the property `Vue.config.devtools` is `true`, in production mode it is `false`!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It does exactly what the OP asked.  Confirmed working on Vue 2.6.11 as well.

Comment: I tried this in Vue 3.0 and it did not work (@user1192887 mentions Vue 3.11 in Sept 2019, but 3.0 wasn't released until 2020, so am confused by what 3.11 refers to?).
As described below by @Toxiro, I got this working in Vue3 with:
`process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'`

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely the most simple solution is to check for the window.location from you Vue component. That would look something like this:

```
if (window.location.href === 'YOUR DEVELOPMENT URL') {
    //preset form values here
}
```

Comment: I guess this works! Not sure if it exactly answers my question but it is a solution nonetheless :)

Answer (score 9):

Using `.env` file is a common way to set environmental variables used in a lot of stacks. It makes sense to use it in Vue, not to try to reinvent the wheel.

Here's a little test, which will show what conditions and options you have.

Build your project this this command:

```
vue-cli-service build
```

**.env file:**

```
#.env
NODE_ENV=development
DDD=development
VUE_APP_NODE_ENV=development
```

**Vue component:**

```
mounted() {
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // OUTPUT: production
    console.log(process.env.DDD); // OUTPUT: undefined
    console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_NODE_ENV); // OUTPUT: development
},
```

**NODE_ENV** is set by `vue-cli-service`. You can have multiple `.env` files and use `vue-cli-service build --mode staging` to [run different configurations](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables).

There are environment variables used during build and **client-side env variables** used in the component code. So you cannot use something like `DDD` in your client-side code, because Vue will ignore it.

You can create your own env variable **prefixed with VUE_APP_** and use them in your client-side code for any checks. [Docs ref](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code).
`VUE_APP_NODE_ENV` will work fine in our test.

**NOTE**

Parsing your url is not the best choice. If you use somethings like this `window.location.href.indexOf("localhost")`, it will not work for `127.0.0.1`. There were a few times I had to run the project on a FQDN, and this check will not work for it eaither.

Answer (score 4):

Try using .env files.

> You can specify env variables by placing the following files in your
>   project root:
>
> .env                # loaded in all cases .env.local          # loaded
>   in all cases, ignored by git .env.[mode]         # only loaded in
>   specified mode .env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode,
>   ignored by git

plus

> Env Loading Priorities
>
> An env file for a specific mode (e.g. .env.production) will take
>   higher priority than a generic one (e.g. .env).

Docs: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Answer (score 4):

This is how Vue checks wether it is in development mode:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
  process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' &&
  typeof console !== 'undefined'
)
```

Source: [GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/platforms/web/runtime/index.js)

Note: I removed the check `config.productionTip !== false` from the code, because it is used only to turn off the "production tip" even if Vue is running in in development mode.

[Gene Parcellano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310302/2731944) works great as long as you are using Webpack, but this **might** be a bit more robust.

**Edit:**

It would be easy to combine both answers like that:

```js
if (
  window.webpackHotUpdate || (
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" &&
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test" &&
    typeof console !== "undefined"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note for `Vue 3` using `Vite`, you can do this via:

```js
if (import.meta.env.PROD) {
    console.log('PRODUCTION!')
}
```

for production, and

```js
if (import.meta.env.DEV) {
    console.log('DEVELOPMENT!');
}
```

for development.

Read here for more: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this in Vue 3 is:

import.meta.env.MODE

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

For my particular case where I use pug and just wanted to conditionally add some elements to a component I set the `options.data` prop of `pug-plain-loader` in my `webpack.config.js` such that the loader looks like the following:

```
{
  resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'pug-plain-loader',
      options: {
          // Use whatever you'd use to detect mode in the webpack config
          data: { mode: process.env['PRODUCTION'] ? 'production' : 'development' },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Here's the full `webpack.config.js` I'm using: https://github.com/SuperuserLabs/thankful/blob/5913d9d0bb02e6d2f3b88c541477dc557caa4148/webpack.config.js#L76-L88

After which I could do:

```
if mode === 'development'
  | Only shown in development mode
```

For the general case, this was harder than I first anticipated. Although someone good at Webpack could probably do this pretty easily.

Answer (score -2):

I usually use:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("localhost") >= 0) {
  // Development mode    
}
```

Or:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("localhost") < 0) {
  // Production mode    
}
```

By just searching for part of the development URL like `localhost` you don't need to be so specific with the rest of the address. This works anywhere in your project, unlike `process.env.NODE_ENV` which won't work in the `index.html` file for example.