# How can I know the Vue.js environment is development or production?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I know the Vue.js environment is development or production ?

In my `AxiosConfig`'s `config.js`:

```
AxiosConfig:{
    baseURL:dev.NODE_ENV.BASE_API,
    responseType: "json",
    withCredentials: true,
    ...
```

You see the `BASE_API` in there:

there is the definition of `dev.NODE_ENV`:

```
  dev.NODE_ENV = {
    BASE_API: 'http://localhost:8000',
    APP_ORIGIN: 'http://103.20.32.16:8000/'
  }
```

How can I check the environment is development or production?

then in the `AxiosConfig` config.js I can use the judgement, when `npm run build I will not need to change the`baseURL` then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How check if Vue is in development mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257650/how-check-if-vue-is-in-development-mode)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `process.env.NODE_ENV` and test for `development` or `production`. You might want to replace your `dev.NODE_ENV.BASE_API` with something like `process.env.NODE_ENV.BASE_API`.

Further to this, if you're using the `vue-cli-service` to bootstrap and build your app, you can use `.env` files and switch the `baseURL` using those, depending upon your environment. You can find out about it in more detail here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: not work .  window.process is undefined in chrome in production mode. (npm run build)

Comment: work in browser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310302/1586797

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're in a browser, like me (using vue.esm-browser[.prod].js), you can also use this:

```
if (window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.enabled) {
    ... // do stuff
}
```

This is only true in development mode. I use this in my console logging .

Answer (score -1):

as normally  when  you  run the command  **npm run dev**  then  it  will be  a  webpack development server and if you run **npm run build**  then  it  will be  for  production  use  and  it  will  make  a minified version of it in the dist folder