# How to handle api request with window

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3, usefetch

I have my development environment (localhost) and then my production environment (something.com). I wanted to make my code more flexible, so I do not have to update my useFetch requests to my backend each time I change environments, so I use the following snippet to get the base URI:

```
      const getProducts = async () => {
    isLoading.value = true;
    
    return await useFetch(window.location.origin + '/assets/json/data.json', {
      onRequestError({ request, options, error }) {
        console.log(error);
        isLoading.value = false;
      },
      onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
        let pricing = new Map(response._data['Regency Pricing'].map(o => [o['Part Num'], o]))
        products.value = response._data['Product Info'].map(o => ({ ...pricing.get(o['Pricing Reference Name']), ...o }))
        setFilters();
        isLoading.value = false;
      },
      onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
        console.log(request.error);
        isLoading.value = false;
      }
    });
  };
```

Using window however seems to draw the following error:

```
[nitro] [unhandledRejection] ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

The code works, but this pollutes my terminal window where I try to watch for errors. I just keep getting this, and I am not sure how I should be handling the base URI to make this work better without those warnings/errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72041740/how-to-set-global-api-baseurl-used-in-usefetch-in-nuxt-3

Comment: You can check the environment and use the proper baseURL. `const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV ===  'development' ? 'dev server url' : 'prod server url'`. Of course it is better to use .env file to tune the baseURL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272553/how-can-i-know-the-vue-js-environment-is-development-or-production

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know the Vue.js environment is development or production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272553/how-can-i-know-the-vue-js-environment-is-development-or-production)

Comment: @Michal Levy your response is very close to what I want. However, Raais notes using process.env.NODE_ENV where as this responses uses BASE_URL. Could one of you draft up the answer which is most appropriate for a basic Nuxt3 install hosted on azure static web apps and what to put in Nuxt config(if default is SSR then thats what I am using)? Il accept that answer.