# How to call Vue instance in chrome console, if he created in a separated file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to call Vue instance in chrome console, if it created in a separated file `new Vue({ ... })`. Like `console.log(vm.user.id)`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: {
      id: 1,
      title: 'TEST VUE'
    }
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the Vue DevTools installed it will create aliases for your Vue instances when you click on them:

[image: Vue DevTools]

Note the light text to the right of the component name. It may be hard to see on some screens.

In the picture above, `$vm1` and `$vm2` are accessible in the console and will refer to the corresponding Vue instances.

As you click around in the DevTools these aliases will change. `$vm0` will refer to the last component you clicked on.

Comment: For any brave souls trying out Vue3, the vue3 devtools changed access of selected component in devtools from "$vm0" to "$vm.proxy"

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by using the Vue Chrome extension [as described by @skritle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63665036/2649853). You also get nice UI with bells and whistles to look at the data, computed properties etc if that's what you need.

However, I've had to do this in environments which didn't have the extension. In those scenarios, you can just add the instance to the global object `window` (browser) or `global` (nodejs).

```
const app = new Vue({...});
window.$appRef = app; // Remove this line for release
```

Then in load the app in the browser and you can access it in the console :

```
console.log($appRef)
```

This should only be used as an emergency escape hatch because it pollutes the global object (potentially causing name collisions and memory leaks) and should be cleaned up after use. You can also wrap it in an [if condition to ensure it is used only during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257650/how-check-if-vue-is-in-development-mode)

```
if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' &&
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test' &&
    typeof console !== 'undefined'
){
    window.$appRef = app;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but then how do you access the data please?  Chrome just tells me that app is a proxy

Comment: @Richard sorry, just saw this - you can access it like you would in the app (use `$appRef.somePropertyOnTheVueInstance`)

Answer (score 0):

Question already has it's accepted answer, but it's worth mentioning the recommended pattern to capture different instance for vue - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Creating-a-Vue-Instance

Just make your own custom `variable` for different `vue instances`

```js
// Use var to mark this variable a global, make sure it's wrapped directly to global execution context, so that you can get it at window scope
var vueInstance1 = new Vue({ 
  el: '#app1',
  data: { title: 'Vue Instance 1' }
})
var vueInstance2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: { title: 'Vue Instance 2' }
})

console.log('Instance 1- ', vueInstance1.title ) // Easily access to instance 1
console.log('Instance 2- ', vueInstance2.title ) // Easily access to instance 2
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app1">{{ title }}</div>
<div id="app2">{{ title }}</div>
```